# Class Properties are inaccessible

Tags: c#

I currently have a Class that firstly looks like this:

```
public class Controller
{

    public class Configuration
    {

        // Properties of the Database
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string BusinessID { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }

    }
```

I then have a few functions that actually bind data to the properties - which works fine. However, I cannot seem to find any documentation on accessing the class properties. I have tried:

```
Controller ctrl;
ctrl = new Controller();
```

However, `ctrl` does not hold any of these values/properties; neither does it hold the `Configuration` class.

Is there something wrong with this structure which is why `Configuration` is inaccessible or could anyone possible help me find a solution to obtaining the `Name`, `BusinessID` and `Address` ?

EDIT: I want to obtain the properties outside the class in the `aspx.cs` file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Inside the class Controller you need an instance of the class Configuration to set/get values

Comment: So inside the main class method I could do: `public Controller()
 {
        Configuration config;
        config = new Configuration();
 }` ? Thanks for this by the way!

Comment: @Dmitry: can you clarify this? How would Java instantiate it automatically?

Comment: @KyleE4K exactly. The important thing is the declaration and initialization of the member variable that represents the configuration of a controller. This is called [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) on oop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're aiming for this setup:

```
public class Controller
{
    public Controller()
    {
        this.Config = new Configuration();
    }

    public Configuration Config { get; set; }
}

public class Configuration
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string BusinessID { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
Controller ctrl;
ctrl = new Controller();
Console.WriteLine(ctrl.Configuration.Name);
```

In your original code there is a class *defined* inside another class. In my example `Controller` has a *property* of type `Configuration`, which is instantiated in the constructor (`public Controller()`).

Comment: This worked! Thank-you, I didn't realise you had to create the instance of both classes and especially of it inside the 1st. Thanks-again! Ill mark when I can

Answer (score 3):

If I correctly understood your use case, what is below is one way to go.

You can create an instance for the second class in this way:

```
Controller.Configuration ac = new Controller.Configuration();
```

Comment: I fail to see how this will compile using the code provided by the OP.

Answer (score 3):

Class are just blue-prints for your actual instances. Your code defines two classes but the enclosing one (Controller) doesn't have a property to access the enclosed inner class (Configuration)

If you want to set/get the properties of an instance of a Configuration class that belongs to an instance of a Controller class you should declare a member property in the Controller class of type Configuration

```
public class Controller
{

    public class Configuration
    {

        // Properties of the Database
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string BusinessID { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }

    }

    // If you don't want external code set the internal instance remove the set method 
    public Configuration ctrlConfig {get;set;}
    public Controller()
    {
         // Remember to initialize the inner instance of the configuration
         ctrlConfig = new Configuration()
    }
}
```

And now somewhere else

```
Controller ctrl;
ctrl = new Controller();
ctrl.ctrlConfig.Name = "YourConfigName";
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
public class Controller
{
    Configuration c;

    public class Configuration
    {

        // Properties of the Database
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string BusinessID { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }

    }
```

}

then you will be able to acces those values:

```
  Controller ctrl = new Controller();
            ctrl.c = new Configuration();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have defined a Class (Controller) and a inner class (Controller.Configuration)

So the properties you defined are domain of class Controller.Configuration and not of controller.

So you should:

```
// istantiate a controller.configuration instance
Controller.Configuration p = new Controller.Configuration();
// and use his properties
p.Name = "test";
```

Otherwhise you can create a property of type Configuration in Controller and you can use that..

```
public class Controller
{
    public Controller()
    {
        Config = new Configuration();
    }
    public class Configuration
    {

        // Properties of the Database
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string BusinessID { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }

    }

    public Configuration Config { get; set; }

}


// istantiate a controller.configuration instance
Controller cont = new Controller();
// and use his properties
cont.Config.Name = "test";
```

Answer (score 0):

For it to work there are two possibilities (it's unclear from the question which you were expecting)

#### 1. Insantiate

You need an instance of the `Configuration` class, and initialize it in the constructor

```
public Configuration Configuration_Instance {get;set;}

public Controller() {
  Configuration_Instance = new Configuration();
}
```

and use

```
ctrl.Configuration_Instance.Name //etc.
```

#### 2. Use static

make `Configuration` static

```
public static class Configuration {
    public static string Name { get; set; }
    public static string BusinessID { get; set; }
    public static string Address { get; set; }
}
```

and use

```
ctrl.Configuration.Name //etc.
```